# Failed to compile using mpich and gcc

Tags: gcc, mpi, mpich, mpic++

I have compiled mpich 3.2 with gcc 4.8.3 on centos. Everything seems to be fine. Then I wrote a simple test program,

```
#include "mpi.h"
int main(int argc,char **argv)
{}
```

and use the mpic++ to compile. Then errors return,

/home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memcpy'
/home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to`__intel_sse2_strncmp'
/home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to `_intel_fast_memset'
/home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to`__intel_sse2_strlen'

What exactly goes wrong? I'm so confused that the error seems to be related with intel compilers, but I use gcc to compile mpich by the command,

```
./configure --prefix=/home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/ CC=gcc CXX=gcc F77=gfortran FC=gfortran
```

I have added /home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/bin to PATH and /home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

mpicc -v shows：

```
mpicc for MPICH version 3.2
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/setups/gcc-4.8.3/build/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.8.3/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/home/setups/gcc-4.8.3/build --with-gmp=/home/setups/gmp-6.1.2/build --with-mpfr=/home/setups/mpfr-3.1.5/build --with-mpc=/home/setups/mpc-1.0.3/build --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)
```

Comment: How do you setup your paths? What does mpicc -v print? What does which mpicc print? How did you configure mpich?

Comment: `CXX` is the program to compile C++ files and in your case `g++`

Comment: @VladimirF I added the path to mpicc in PATH. mpicc -v seems to be fine. I have added the output of mpicc -v in my quesion.

Comment: @Arash Do you mean I should use CXX=g++ in the configure? I tried but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Take a look at the `config.log` file in the same folder that you run the `./configure` script. Look for anything intel related in the log file. Also look for errors/warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You might find your solution at the open-mpi.org site and their faq for building MPI.  For example, item 17.

> A common mistake when building Open MPI with the Intel compiler suite
>   is to accidentally specify the Intel C compiler as the C++ compiler.
>   Specifically, recent versions of the Intel compiler renamed the C++
>   compiler "icpc" (it used to be "icc", the same as the C compiler).
>   Users accustomed to the old name tend to specify "icc" as the C++
>   compiler, which will then cause a failure late in the Open MPI build
>   process because a C++ code will be compiled with the C compiler. Bad
>   Things then happen. The solution is to be sure to specify that the C++
>   compiler is "icpc", not "icc". For example:

https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=building

Answer (score 0):

> /home/setups/mpich-3.2/build/lib/libmpi.so: undefined reference to _intel_fast_memcpy'

This strongly suggests an Intel compiler was used to build mpich.

That can happen is `gcc/g++/gfortran` is not in your `PATH` or if your environment points to the Intel compiler (e.g. `CC=icc` or `CXX=icpc` or `FC=ifort`).